# CSS line comments break the file

Tags: css

I have a CSS file, my editor has a "mini map" and ASCII block text headings so I can navigate the file faster.

I have an odd bug where some of the headings break the CSS.

Using block comments or removing them fix the rules but some work regardless e.g. the ones between the ROUND heading and the PLAYER heading.

Here is the broken CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  ##    ##    ###    ##     ## ####  ######      ###    ######## ####  #######  ##    ##  //
//  ###   ##   ## ##   ##     ##  ##  ##    ##    ## ##      ##     ##  ##     ## ###   ##  //
//  ####  ##  ##   ##  ##     ##  ##  ##         ##   ##     ##     ##  ##     ## ####  ##  //
//  ## ## ## ##     ## ##     ##  ##  ##   #### ##     ##    ##     ##  ##     ## ## ## ##  //
//  ##  #### #########  ##   ##   ##  ##    ##  #########    ##     ##  ##     ## ##  ####  //
//  ##   ### ##     ##   ## ##    ##  ##    ##  ##     ##    ##     ##  ##     ## ##   ###  //
//  ##    ## ##     ##    ###    ####  ######   ##     ##    ##    ####  #######  ##    ##  //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

.navbar {
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.navbar a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: #9d9d9d;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  ########  #######  ########  ##     ##  ######   //
//  ##       ##     ## ##     ## ###   ### ##    ##  //
//  ##       ##     ## ##     ## #### #### ##        //
//  ######   ##     ## ########  ## ### ##  ######   //
//  ##       ##     ## ##   ##   ##     ##       ##  //
//  ##       ##     ## ##    ##  ##     ## ##    ##  //
//  ##        #######  ##     ## ##     ##  ######   //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

.form-control-on-black {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.form-control-on-black:focus {
    border-color: white;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-on-black {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: white;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   ######  ########  ######   ##     ## ######## ##    ## ########  ######   //
//  ##    ## ##       ##    ##  ###   ### ##       ###   ##    ##    ##    ##  //
//  ##       ##       ##        #### #### ##       ####  ##    ##    ##        //
//   ######  ######   ##   #### ## ### ## ######   ## ## ##    ##     ######   //
//        ## ##       ##    ##  ##     ## ##       ##  ####    ##          ##  //
//  ##    ## ##       ##    ##  ##     ## ##       ##   ###    ##    ##    ##  //
//   ######  ########  ######   ##     ## ######## ##    ##    ##     ######   //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

//   ######  ####### #     # #     # ######
//   #     # #     # #     # ##    # #     #
//   #     # #     # #     # # #   # #     #
//   ######  #     # #     # #  #  # #     #
//   #   #   #     # #     # #   # # #     #
//   #    #  #     # #     # #    ## #     #
//   #     # #######  #####  #     # ######

#round-card {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.card-space {
    color: #337ab7;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.card-space:hover {
    color: #337ab7;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #337ab7;
}

#submit-card-btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 60px;
}


//   ######  #          #    #     # ####### ######
//   #     # #         # #    #   #  #       #     #
//   #     # #        #   #    # #   #       #     #
//   ######  #       #     #    #    #####   ######
//   #       #       #######    #    #       #   #
//   #       #       #     #    #    #       #    #
//   #       ####### #     #    #    ####### #     #

#player-cards {
  background-color: black;
}

#card-nav-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

#card-nav-wrap>#left-fade {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

#card-nav-wrap>#right-fade {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}

#card-nav {
    z-index: 1;
}


//    #####   #####  ####### ######  #######
//   #     # #     # #     # #     # #
//   #       #       #     # #     # #
//    #####  #       #     # ######  #####
//         # #       #     # #   #   #
//   #     # #     # #     # #    #  #
//    #####   #####  ####### #     # #######

#score {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.label-czar {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   ######     ###    ########  ########   ######   //
//  ##    ##   ## ##   ##     ## ##     ## ##    ##  //
//  ##        ##   ##  ##     ## ##     ## ##        //
//  ##       ##     ## ########  ##     ##  ######   //
//  ##       ######### ##   ##   ##     ##       ##  //
//  ##    ## ##     ## ##    ##  ##     ## ##    ##  //
//   ######  ##     ## ##     ## ########   ######   //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

.card {
    position: relative;
}

.card p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.card-light{
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

.card-dark{
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.card-big {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 240px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 5%;
}

.card-big p {
    font-size: 26px;
}

.card-small{
  width: 170%;
  max-width: 120px;
  height: 190px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.card-small p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: The odd bug is that some of the comments don't break anything. CSS supports only the block `/* */` comments.

Comment: Have you tried using comment block `/* */`, which is the only valid comment in CSS? The `//` works in Sass/Less, though, but I don't think you use that.

Comment: @OriDrori yes it is a bit odd...

Comment: @kamyl thanks, I usually use sass, forgot that // is not valid.

Comment: The good explanation how `//` syntax in CSS "works" is here: http://www.xanthir.com/b4U10 (from the author of most CSS specs!). TL/DR: it's just invalid code, and as _any_ invalid code it invalidates all the code after it till the end of the block of the corresponding level.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, my IDE has an hotkey for it :) not much effort at all, I only posted this question because the behavior of the line comment one was unexpected.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, I misconfigured the CSS template as I use SASS more often. Amazingly it now doesn't break my code! As for your comment about the file not being inspected... it's for my own navigation of my code, I tend to minimize web resources before deploying...

Also I do get bored, I am wasting my time replying to you :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your `//` with `/* */`.

The only valid comment type in CSS is the block one, `/* */`. The inline comment, `//` works in Sass/Less, though.